# Algoritmo de calculo de preço não exibe o resultado corretamente

Tags: c

Estou tentando fazer um algoritmo para calcular o que deve ser pago por um produto, considerando o preço normal de etiqueta e a escolha de condição de pagamento, mas ele não consegue calcular, fica exibindo o valor 100.

```
#include < stdio.h >
#include < stdlib.h > 

void main()
{
    float valor;
    int cod_pagamento;

    printf("Insira o valor do produto: R$");
    scanf("%f", &valor);

    printf("Insira a forma de pagamento: ");
    scanf("%d", &cod_pagamento);

     switch(cod_pagamento){
        case 1:
            printf("Voce vai pagar R$ %.2f", valor-((10/100)*valor));
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Voce vai pagar R$ %.2f", valor-((5/100)*valor));
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Voce vai pagar R$ %.2f", valor);
            break;
        case 4:
            printf("Voce vai pagar R$ %.2f", valor+((10/100)*valor));
            break;
        default:
            printf("Selecione uma das opções para realizar o pagamento");
            break;
    }   
}
```

Comment: No primeiro case está faltando uma ")"

Comment: Consertei isso, mas ele continua exibindo 100 em todas as opções. Não consigo efetuar a operação de reduzir ou aumentar o preço na função printf

Comment: Você está fazendo aritmética inteira. Experimente dividir por `100.0` no lugar de dividir por `100`

Comment: Deu certo. Muito Obrigado, mas por que funciona somente eu colocar o numero decimal na divisão?

Comment: @Carlos mais tarde eu respondo. Não me deixe esquecer. Estou agora ocupado, mas tenho algumas respostas a respeito de pontos flutuantes, talvez isso abra sua mente. E, sim, é muito confuso para quem está começando, não se assuste. Com o tempo se acostuma

Answer (score -1):

Você pode fazer como por exemplo (já que os valores são estáticos) :

```
case 1:
    aux = (valor - 1) * valor;
    printf ("Voce vai pagar R$ %.2f", aux );
```

Comment: como você mesmo comentou, o programa tem erros sintáticos, e é isso que está desencadeando o problema descrito.

Answer (score -1):

Você não deve estar rodando o mesmo programa que compila.

Como foi reparo nos comentáris, está faltando um `)` no primeiro case -

```
       printf("Voce vai pagar R$ %.2f", valor-((10/100)*valor));
```

Abre 3 parenteses, e fecha só 2. Isso acontece em todos os seus outros `printf`: nessa condição o programa não compila. Você pode estar alterando o código fonte, mas o programa que é executado é sempre o último que conseguiu ser compilado - no caso deve ser algum teste que só imprimia "100".

É só prestar atenção nas mensagens de erro do seu compilador e seu ambiente para ver os erros de sintaxe, bem como na data e hora do arquivo executável (".exe", se for windows) que você está rodando.